# Zero Occurrence in regular Expressions (Unix)

Tags: regex, unix, grep

Can someone explain what it means by zero occurrence when we use * as regular expression while using it with egrep or grep?

Suppose I have an expression like: **"a*"**

Does that means I have a pattern which starts with a or aaaaa..... or bob or does it have to start with a?

Comment: If you have `a*`, it means it can match anything, because `a*` can match zero characters, i.e. an empty string, and all strings start with an empty string.

Comment: What if I have a*$ ? Does that mean it has to end with atleast 1 "a" ?

Comment: No it still matches anything, because all strings end with an empty string as well. Generally you should not construct a regex that can match zero length pattern. It should at least be `a+$` for it to be meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `a*` will match `bob`, as will `^ba*o` and `^boa*`, since the Kleene star matches zero or more occurrences.

Consider the word `bazaar`. You might use `za*`, `zaa*`, or `zaaa*r` to match it. To insist on one or more occurrences, you might use `za+r`. For two or more use `zaa+r`. To insist on exactly two occurrences, use `za{2}r`.